# Powershell change output object name from datatable

Tags: powershell, datatable, select-object

I'm outputting a couple of objects from a data table to a .csv file and wanted to change the object names.

This works fine:

```
$dataset.tables[0] | select-object System.ItemName, System.ItemPathDisplay | Export-Csv -Path D:\SEARCH_RESULT.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

However I'd like to change System.ItemName to SKU and have tried the following:

```
$dataset.tables[0] | select-object @{N='SKU';E={$_.System.ItemName}}, System.ItemPathDisplay | Export-Csv -Path D:\SEARCH_RESULT.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This gives the right column heading but blank rows. So tried this which give rows but they all say SYSTEM.ITEMNAME:

```
$dataset.tables[0] | select-object @{N='SKU';E={$dataset.tables[0].Columns['SYSTEM.ITEMNAME']}}, System.ItemPathDisplay | Export-Csv -Path D:\SEARCH_RESULT.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Clearly I'm not referencing the object correctly. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$_.System.ItemName` to `$_.'System.ItemName'`

Your property name is `System.ItemName`, and if a property name itself contains `.`, it must be *quoted* - otherwise, PowerShell interprets it as a *nested* [property access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#member-access-operator-)

That is, `$_.System.ItemName` looks for a property on object `$_` named `System` first, and then for an `ItemName` property on the first property's value; PowerShell defaults to `$null` when accessing non-existent properties.

Contrast this with the use of `System.ItemName` as an *argument* passed to the (positionally implied) `-Property` parameter of the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) cmdlet, where the argument is *always* interpreted as a *single* property name (whether you quote it or not).
In other words: `Select-Object` doesn't *directly* support *nested* property access, but you can do it via a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties), as in your approach.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation. Much appreciated!